# Add Background image to Rails 4 using Foundation 5

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I want to add a background image to my Rails 4 app. I am using the `foundation-rails` gem version 5.4.5.0

I have a div with the class `content` wrapping my yield in the application.html.erb

Here is the css:

```
.content {
    margin-top: 60px;
    background-image: url("/images/brickwall_@2X.png"): repeat;
}
```

Comment: Please note that the image is in app/assets/images and the css is in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

Comment: The `: repeat` is not valid syntax for background-image. You may want to use `background` and remove the second `:`. If you change it to `background: url("/images/brickwall_@2X.png") repeat;` does it work?

Comment: I did that and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to `background-image: url('brickwall_@2X.png')`. Rails automatically searches the asset pipeline for your image files in the assets/images folder, so if it the image is saved in assets/images, you don't need to tell Rails where to go.